# AngularJS, php & mysql database updation from datatable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, database

I have the code with showing  data from json file, but i need update table single row data to the database. In my code I can update only angulajs table. So i need one more thing, need to update that one mysql also. hence, i need to know how data will pass mysql to using js& PHP, the code is given below.

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [

        'ui.grid',
        'ui.grid.pagination',
        'ui.grid.selection',
        'ui.grid.cellNav',
        'ui.grid.expandable',
        'ui.grid.edit',
        'ui.grid.rowEdit',
        'ui.grid.saveState',
        'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
        'ui.grid.pinning',
        'ui.grid.moveColumns',
        'ui.grid.exporter',
        'ui.grid.infiniteScroll',
        'ui.grid.importer',
        'ui.grid.grouping'
    ]);

app.filter('genderFilter', function () {
    var genderHash = {
        'M': 'male',
        'F': 'female'
    };


    app.gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered(scope,() => {
        if (!gridApi.grid.expandable.expandedAll && !initialized)
        {
            gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows();
            initialized = true;
         }
});

    return function (input) {
        var result;
        var match;
        if (!input) {
            return '';
        } else if (result = genderHash[input]) {
            return result;
        } else if ((match = input.match(/(.+)( \([$\d,.]+\))/)) && (result = genderHash[match[1]])) {
            return result + match[2];
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    };
});

app.filter('maritalFilter', function () {
    var genderHash = {
        'M': 'Married',
        'S': 'Single'
    };

    return function (input) {
        var result;
        var match;
        if (!input) {
            return '';
        } else if (result = genderHash[input]) {
            return result;
        } else if ((match = input.match(/(.+)( \([$\d,.]+\))/)) && (result = genderHash[match[1]])) {
            return result + match[2];
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    };
})

app.controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', 'uiGridConstants', '$q', '$interval',
    function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout, uiGridConstants, $q, $interval) {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableSelectAll: true,
            selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
            rowHeight: 35,
            showGridFooter: true
        };

        $scope.convertDate = function (str) {
            var date = new Date(str),
                mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("/");
        };
        var expandableScope = {};

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering:true,
            expandableRowTemplate: '<div style="padding:5px;"><div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions[0]" ui-grid-edit  ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-selection style="height:340px;display:inline-block;"></div></div>',
            expandableRowHeight: 350,
            columnDefs: [

                { name: 'Project', enableCellEdit: true,  },
                /* {
                    name: "",
                    field:"fake",
                    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >' +
                    '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.enterEditMode($event)">Delete</button>' +
                    '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.enterEditMode($event)">Edit</button>' +
                    '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.saveEdit($event)">Update</button>' +
                    '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.cancelEdit($event)">Cancel</button>' +
                    '</div>',
                     enableCellEdit: false,
                     enableFiltering:false,
                     enableSorting: false,
                     showSortMenu : false,
                     enableColumnMenu: false,
                }*/

                /*{ name: 'managerid', enableCellEdit: true },
                //{
                //    name: 'hiredate', enableCellEdit: true, type: "date", cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy/MM/dd"',
                //    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.convertDate(row.entity[col.field])}}</div>'
                //},
                {
                    name: 'title', enableCellEdit: true,
                    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><div ng-class="{\'viewr-dirty\' : row.inlineEdit.entity[col.field].isValueChanged }">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div></div>'
                },
                // { name: 'birthdate', enableCellEdit: true, type: "date", cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy/MM/dd"' },
                {
                    name: 'maritalstatus', enableCellEdit: true, cellFilter: "maritalFilter",
                    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
                    editDropdownValueLabel: 'maritalstatus',
                    editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                        { id: 'M', maritalstatus: 'Married' },
                        { id: 'S', maritalstatus: 'Single' }]
                },
                {
                    name: 'gender', enableCellEdit: true, cellFilter: 'genderFilter',
                    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
                    editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender',
                    editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                        { id: 'M', gender: 'male' },
                        { id: 'F', gender: 'female' }]
                },*/

            ],
            enableGridMenu: true,
            virtualizationThreshold: 60,
            expandableRowScope: {
                subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable'
            }
        }

        //$scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = true;

        $http.get('https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/data/employeeData.json')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(0, 55);; //[data[0], data[1]];
            });

        $scope.info = {};

        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            //set gridApi on scope
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
                $log.log(msg);
            });

            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, function (rows) {
                var msg = 'rows changed ' + rows.length;
                $log.log(msg);
            });

            gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
                var selectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();

                if (newValue != oldValue) {

                    rowEntity.state = "Changed";
                    //Get column
                    var rowCol = $scope.gridApi.cellNav.getFocusedCell().col.colDef.name;

                    angular.forEach(selectedRows, function (item) {
                        item[rowCol] = rowEntity[rowCol];// $scope.convertDate(rowEntity[rowCol]);
                        item.state = "Changed";
                        item.isDirty = false;
                        item.isError = false;
                    });

                }
            });

            gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, function (rowEntity) {
                // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
                //Get all selected rows
                var selectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
                //var rowCol = $scope.gridApi.cellNav.getFocusedCell().col.colDef.name;
                var promise = $q.defer();
                $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, promise.promise);

                $interval(function () {
                    if (rowEntity.gender === 'male') {
                        promise.reject();
                    } else {
                        promise.resolve();
                    }
                }, 3000, 1);
            })

            gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function (row) {
                if (row.isExpanded) {

                    row.entity.subGridOptions =[{
                        virtualizationThreshold: 60,
                        enableFiltering:true,
                       // expandableRowTemplate: '<div style="padding:5px;"><div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions[0]" ui-grid-edit  ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-selection style="height:340px;display:inline-block;"></div></div>',
                        //expandableRowHeight: 350,
                        columnDefs: [
                            { name: 'firstname', enableCellEdit: true, width: 100},
                            { name: 'Activity Description', width: 500 },
                            { name: 'Start' },
                            { name: 'Department' },
                            { name: 'Remarks' },
                            {
                            name: "",
                            field:"fake",
                            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >' +
                            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.enterEditMode($event)">Delete</button>' +
                            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.enterEditMode($event)">Edit</button>' +
                            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.saveEdit($event)">Update</button>' +
                            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.cancelEdit($event)">Cancel</button>' +
                            '</div>',
                            enableCellEdit: false,
                            enableFiltering:false,
                            enableSorting: false,
                            showSortMenu : false,
                            enableColumnMenu: false,
                        }
                        ],
                        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                            $scope.text = gridApi;
                            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                                console.log(row);
                            });

                            gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, function (rowEntity) {
                                // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
                                //Get all selected rows
                                var selectedRows = $scope.text.selection.getSelectedRows();
                                //var rowCol = $scope.gridApi.cellNav.getFocusedCell().col.colDef.name;
                                var promise = $q.defer();
                                $scope.text.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, promise.promise);
                                $interval(function () {
                                    if (rowEntity.gender === 'male') {
                                        promise.reject();
                                    } else {
                                        promise.resolve();
                                    }
                                }, 3000, 1);
                            })
                        }
                    }],

                      $http.get('https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/data/employeeContact.json')
                            .success(function (data) {
                                row.entity.subGridOptions[0].data = data.slice(0, 45);
                            });

                }
            });


        };
    }]);


angular.module('ui.grid').factory('InlineEdit', ['$interval', '$rootScope', 'uiGridRowEditService',
    function ($interval, $rootScope, uiGridRowEditService) {
        function inlineEdit(entity, index, grid) {
            this.grid = grid;
            this.index = index;
            this.entity = {};
            this.isEditModeOn = false;
            this.init(entity);
        }

        inlineEdit.prototype = {
            init: function (rawEntity) {
                var self = this;

                for (var prop in rawEntity) {
                    self.entity[prop] = {
                        value: rawEntity[prop],
                        isValueChanged: false,
                        isSave: false,
                        isCancel: false,
                        isEdit: false
                    }
                }
            },

            enterEditMode: function (event) {
                event && event.stopPropagation();
                var self = this;
                self.isEditModeOn = true;

                // cancel all rows which are in edit mode
                self.grid.rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    if (row.inlineEdit && row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn && row.uid !== self.grid.rows[self.index].uid) {
                        row.inlineEdit.cancelEdit();
                    }
                });

                // Reset all the values
                for (var prop in self.entity) {
                    self.entity[prop].isSave = false;
                    self.entity[prop].isCancel = false;
                    self.entity[prop].isEdit = true;
                }
            },

            saveEdit: function (event) {
                event && event.stopPropagation();
                var self = this;

                self.isEditModeOn = false;

                for (var prop in self.entity) {
                    self.entity[prop].isSave = true;
                    self.entity[prop].isEdit = false;
                }

                uiGridRowEditService.saveRow(self.grid, self.grid.rows[self.index])();
            },

            cancelEdit: function (event) {
                event && event.stopPropagation();
                var self = this;

                self.isEditModeOn = false;
                for (var prop in self.entity) {
                    self.entity[prop].isCancel = true;
                    self.entity[prop].isEdit = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return inlineEdit;
    }]);
```

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/Css/ui-grid.css" />
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/Js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/Js/vendor/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" class="">
    <div class="" ng-controller="gridCtrl">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-move-columns="" ui-grid-edit="" ui-grid-row-edit="" ui-grid-selection="" ui-grid-expandable="" class="grid" style="height:800px"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you make your question a bit more clear?

Comment: The above mentioned code, will show data to our display,the updation, but this will not effect database. how we connect database in single row updation.